Do green cards holders need a visa for UK transit?
I am a Dominica citizen holding a US Green Card and I live in the United States. I will be traveling from Chicago to France, but I have to transit 2 hours in the UK. Do I need to obtain a transit visa for the 2-hour layover in the UK?
Thank you

For what it’s worth, citizens of Dominica can visit the UK without a visa in general.

@JohnDoe That seems to have changed on 19 July 2023, after which holders of Dominican passports are usually required to obtain a visa to enter and transit through the UK (though not if they are covered by an exception).

@Henry Thanks for pointing that out!

The UK Government set up a pretty useful tool to check if you need a visa.
In your case, if you don't go through border control (I suppose this is the most likely):

You normally need a Direct Airside Transit visa if you arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through immigration control.
Exemptions
You do not need a Direct Airside Transit visa if you have one of the following:
(...)

a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998

(...)

And if you go through border control:

You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight and will pass through immigration control before you leave the UK.
Transiting without a visa
You may be eligible to transit without a visa if:

you arrive and depart by air
have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

One of the following must also apply:
(...)

you have a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998

(...)

So, no, with a US green card you don't need a visa to transit the UK.
